# Can't create directory in the Wildfly server from the java web application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, wildfly

I want to create a directory structure inside the wild-fly server at the run time of my web java web application. Here is the sample code inside my controller.

```
        String directoryName = null;
        try {
            directoryName = "/parent_folder/subfolder/";
            File directory = new File(directoryName);
            if (! directory.exists()){
                directory.mkdirs();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

This code not firing any exceptions. But it doesn't create the folders too. I debugg with this code. It shows code running successfully without having any exceptions. Additionally my wild-fly server is running on a Ubuntu machine.

---

I changed my code as follows . but the problem is same.

```
   String directoryName = null;
            try {
                directoryName = "/parent_folder/sub-folder/";
                String filePath = new File("").getAbsolutePath();
                filePath.concat(directoryName);
                File directory = new File(filePath);
                if (! directory.exists()){
                    directory.mkdirs();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: Probably looking in the wrong place. Are you using an absolute path just as in your example?

Comment: I also suspected in that way.I searched in the wildfly server but it not found.

Comment: Then try `System.out.println(directory.getAbsolutePath())` to see where exactly the file is being created

Comment: @ernest-kiwele I checked with your code . It printed same structure .(this is the printed result " /parent_folder/subfolder/ ")

Comment: Where are you looking for errors? In the server log file? Does `e.printStackTrace()` send the output to the log you're inspecting (maybe you have custom log configuration)? It has to be simple: either the file gets created, or there's an exception.

Comment: Now ok I could solve the problem. Thanks @Ernest Kiwele

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the API docs for [Java SE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs()). `mkdirs` returns a `boolean` if creation was successful.

Hence, you must change it to:

```
String directoryName = null;
            try {
                directoryName = "/parent_folder/sub-folder/";
                String filePath = new File("").getAbsolutePath();
                filePath.concat(directoryName);
                File directory = new File(filePath);
                if (! directory.exists()){
                    boolean created = directory.mkdirs();
                    if (!created) {
                      //TODO: add your code here
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```